# Objective-C Core Animation or OpenGL Draw Shadow at Angle

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, core-animation, shadow

Hello I am wondering if anyone has ever drawn a shadow on an image view with core animation or OpenGL so that the shadow is at an angle and feathered out in a circle.  That is kind of a vague description so I am attaching an image of what I am trying to achieve.  I have tried working with layers and tried drawing lines in core animation, but nothing seems to be even in the ballpark.  I was thinking of doing this with a texture in OpenGL, would that be the correct approach, if so, how would I go about creating the circular spread on the texture with the gradient?

Let me know if anyone has achieved this and how you went about doing it.

Here is the image of what I am looking to do:

[image]

Comment: Would anyone like a bounty when it comes available on this question?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can't draw a 3D shadow like that with Core Animation. I would say that your options are OpenGL or trying to fake it with an image of a shadow

Comment: Thanks David, I was thinking of trying it with OpenGL

Comment: Do you know how I might do that in OpenGL, just the shadow portion?

Comment: If you are somewhat familiar with OpenGL then you can look at [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/). If you aren't comfortable with OpenGL I would *strongly* recommend that you look at other alternatives first since OpenGL is quite advanced.

Comment: Thanks David, I can navigate my way around OpenGL, I just have never been able to produce a texture or a shadow that is feathered in a 3d gradient like that before.  I will take a look

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this.. may be it will be helpful for you

```
    viewMain = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
viewMain.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:viewMain];

[viewMain.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
[viewMain.layer setShadowRadius:5];

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(10, 10), endPoint = CGPointMake(120, 120);
CGFloat angle = M_PI/3; // 60 degrees in radians
CGPoint v1 = CGPointMake(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, endPoint.y - startPoint.y);
CGPoint v2 = CGPointMake(cosf(angle) * v1.x - sinf(angle) * v1.y,
                         sinf(angle) * v1.x + cosf(angle) * v1.y);
CGPoint thirdPoint = CGPointMake(startPoint.x + v2.x, startPoint.y + v2.y);

UIBezierPath *triangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[triangle moveToPoint:startPoint];
[triangle addLineToPoint:endPoint];
[triangle addLineToPoint:thirdPoint];
[triangle closePath];
// ...

[viewMain.layer setShadowPath:triangle.CGPath];
```

You can modify the UIBezierPath for different angles.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am testing this right now.